# After press on return button the listview hide from UI IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After press, the return button on-screen keyboard the listview hide from the iOS  screen. The same code is running perfectly on Android. I have create the 30 second video that will help you understand the problem.
The code file and Video can be download from here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q4O1KexIHvrCX79AR3CesRXJRWM1o2JR?usp=sharing

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewOrder" ItemTapped="OnActivitySelected" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                      <Frame   HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="Silver"   Padding="3">
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColour}" ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="2">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="35" BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColour}" Padding="10">
                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColour}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                    <Label FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#707070" Text="{Binding GFIELD3}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColour}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source = "{Binding ImageStatus}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest = "20" WidthRequest="20" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                      </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

<StackLayout x:Name="layoutForBluetooth" HeightRequest="200" Padding="5, 5, 5, 5" BackgroundColor="#5DCBEE" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Frame Padding="5,5,5,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" OutlineColor="Black" HasShadow="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="Scan Your Barcode" x:Name="lblDriverNumber" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,10" />
                        <Entry x:Name="txtentry" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black" WidthRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
```

```
async void Txtentry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BiendListview(orderID);
}

 public void BiendListview(int OID)
    {
        try
        {
            List<GenericFields> GN = new List<GenericFields>();
            GN = GetDeliveryOrderItems(OID);
            if (GN != null)
            {
               // listViewOrder.BeginRefresh();
                listViewOrder.ItemsSource = GN;
               // listViewOrder.EndRefresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make a breakpoint to debug your GN's value. From your code:

```
if (GN != null)
{
   // listViewOrder.BeginRefresh();
    listViewOrder.ItemsSource = GN;
   // listViewOrder.EndRefresh();
}
```

This if statement will always be true, since you have construct the `GN` by `List<GenericFields> GN = new List<GenericFields>();`. It will never be null.

You can try to modify it to:

```
if (GN.Count != 0)
{
   // listViewOrder.BeginRefresh();
    listViewOrder.ItemsSource = GN;
   // listViewOrder.EndRefresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Land Lu the GN.Count is always have value. Problem is always after every text change event when I bind my list box go to upper side on the screen. Again after text change it disappear from screen. Please see my video that is only 30 seconds.That you can  Download  from my google drive link

Comment: @A.Goutam I have watched your video, so I think it may be the problem of the listView's ItemsSource.

Comment: Lu -MSFT thanks for your comment. I used the the control https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-fix-keyboard-overlapping-or-covering-entry/ in my AppDelegate KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init(); because of this the list item are going out off screen. But when i comment this line of code from AppDelegate Listbox is not disapper form screen but new problem occured that is keyboard overlap on textbox this happening only in IOS